# How to create new rows for entries that do not exist, in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'cat': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b'], 'br': [1,2,2,3], 'ch': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
'value': [10,20,30,40]})
```

For every `cat` and `br`, I want to add the `ch` that is missing with `value` 0

My final dataframe should look like this:

```
 foo_final = pd.DataFrame({'cat': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 
                          'br': [1,2,2,3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3], 
                          'ch': ['A', 'A', 'B','C','B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B'],
                          'value': [10,20,30,40, 0,0, 0,0,0]})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)
 for `Multiindex` and then [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
foo = foo.set_index(['cat','br','ch']).unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
print (foo)
  cat  br ch  value
0   a   1  A     10
1   a   1  B      0
2   a   1  C      0
3   a   2  A     20
4   a   2  B     30
5   a   2  C      0
6   b   3  A      0
7   b   3  B      0
```